# ajax get image from folder debug

Tags: ajax

```
  function ajax_json(folder){
      var thumbnailbox = $('#thumbnailbox');
      $.ajax({
        url:"json_data.php",
        dataType:"json",
        type:"POST",
        data: {folder: JSON.stringify(folder)},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success:function(d){
          var temp = '';
            for (var o in d) {
                 if (d.hasOwnProperty(o) && d[o].hasOwnProperty('src') && d[o].src !== '') {
                     //create image
                     temp += "<div class='typebox'><img id='typeImg' src=" + d[o].src + "></div>";
                 }
            }
          }, error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log("textStatus = " + textStatus + "\terrorThrown = " + errorThrown);
            alert(XMLHttpRequest.status);
            alert(XMLHttpRequest.readyState);
            alert(textStatus);
        }
      });
    }
```

php

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$folder = $_POST["folder"];
$jsonData = '{';
$dir = $folder."/";
$dirHandle = opendir($dir); 
$i = 0;
while ($file = readdir($dirHandle)) {
    if(!is_dir($file) && preg_match("/.jpg|.gif|.png/i", $file)){
        $i++;
        $src = "$dir$file";
$jsonData .= '"img'.$i.'":{ "num":"'.$i.'","src":"'.$src.'", "name":"'.$file.'" },';
    }
}
closedir($dirHandle);
$jsonData = chop($jsonData, ",");
$jsonData .= '}';
echo $jsonData;
?>
```

error

```
textStatus = parsererror    errorThrown = SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

my intention is the get image from my folder using ajax ,it got error and i cant find what i am missing to have error , can anyone help me take a look? i cant debug it.

Comment: You should not create JSON by hand. That is far too error prone. Instead setup your response array and encode that using the `json_encode()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: could you mention the desired encoded json string?? .. this will help to answer..

Comment: thank you guys ,cause  this is the only code i tested success to get image